# How to build class library project and export only certain DLLs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, class-library

I have a class library project that I set output location for build in a Unity project, when I build it, it exports .net framework files which are already built-in the Unity project, so I delete them every time I build as they make the game size bigger as they include not needed files.

How can I export just the DLL file of the class library.

I also have 2 library projects that share a common library that is exported to unity twice, how can I exclude it?

Comment: Does https://forum.unity.com/threads/compiling-c-scripts-to-dll-files.318803/ answer your question?

Comment: no, this answers if I want to use unity api inside my library project

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to this? I am generally a little bit confused on what is the best approach when building and testing library projects in Visual Studio, that I want to import into Unity. I don't want it to be too much of a manual process every time I make a change.